# Call a Java class in a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to call a Java class from a batch file.

How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to accept an answer or respond if none of the work...

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
java -jar "Path/To/The/Jar/Whatever.jar"
```

I would recommend first jaring up your class(es) and providing a link to the jar.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having:

- a class **Myclass**,
- with a package name of **com.mycomp.util**.

Then:

- use the parent dir of **com** e.g. **c:\src**
  (the folder that contains the com package),
- store the below commands in a batch file:

  ```
  cd c:\\src  
  java -cp jar1;jar2; com.mycomp.util.Myclass
  ```

Execute the batch file to run the Java program.

Answer (score 2):

If you have compiled your `.java` file, and have the `.class` file, containing bytecode for your `main` function, then just run:

```
java myclass
```

where `myclass` is the module name (file has to be `myclass.class`).

Comment: This won't work if myclass isn't in the default package. Also, by Java conventions, it should be "Myclass" instead of "myclass"

Answer (score 1):

Just use this in ur .bat file 
`java -classpath folderName/example.jar; com.example.package.ExampleProgram`
if you are placing the .bat file in the same folder with the jar, then its not necessary to mention the folderName

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Open a new Text File in Notepad.
2. Write the following lines of code, then saves it as "MyFile.bat"
   (Note: Save it as a .BAT File)

   `@ECHO OFF`

    `javac YourClass.java`

    `java YourClass`
3. Now double click the BAT file to execute your Java program.

**Note:** The BAT file and Java Class should be in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

java -jar "C:\path_to_jar_directory\test.jar"
"C:\path_to_arguments\property.properties"
```